# Как сделать скриншот элемента страницы в Awesomium?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, awesomium, скриншот

Пробовал сделать скриншот - выдавало сизую картинку. Может подскажете как сделать скриншот всего контрола, а лучше - определенной части?

**UPD:** Итак, пока нашел решение по поводу скриншота всей страницы:

```
using (WebView vw = WebCore.CreateWebView(1024, 768))
        {
            vw.Source = new Uri("http://ya.ru");

            while (vw.IsLoading)
            {
                WebCore.Update();
            }

            ((BitmapSurface)vw.Surface).SaveToJPEG("D:\\ya.jpg");
            WebCore.Shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: У `BitmapSurface` есть поле `Buffer`, содержащее указатель на буфер пикселей. Можно оттуда выдернуть нужные значения, предварительно узнав местоположение и размеры нужного элемента на странице (через JS, например), и сохранить их в виде картинки.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду пробовать. Я сам наконец нашел нормальную документацию по Awesomium. :) Сейчас разбираюсь со многими моментами. Но пока отпала нужда в скриншоте, выдираю base64 из кода с помощью js и склеиваю потом в одну фотку. Для тренировки :)

Comment: Если необходимо сохранить картинку (со статичной ссылкой) со страницы, то в качестве альтернативы можно сделать так: получить URL картинки с помощью JS, после чего скачать её через C#.

Comment: Ну я так и делаю, только там в src находится base64 картинки, я с помощью js его получаю и преобразовываю в картинку.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, выкроил время написать ответ. Решение я нашел, может кому пригодится. Я совсем не профи, поэтому кому-то может показаться "корявым". Если это так - прошу исправить. Собственно решение:

```
        ((BitmapSurface)webView.Surface).SaveToJPEG("D://screen.jpg");
        string[] rect = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("var a = document.getElementById('Id элемента').getBoundingClientRect();" +
                                                            "a.left + '|' + a.top + '|' + a.width + '|' + a.height").ToString().Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle selection = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(rect[0].Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]), Convert.ToInt32(rect[1].Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]), Convert.ToInt32(rect[2]), Convert.ToInt32(rect[3]));
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile("D://screen.jpg");
        System.Drawing.Bitmap cropBmp = bmp.Clone(selection, bmp.PixelFormat);
```

Из нерешенного:

- Если элемент в данный момент вне экрана, то нужно прокрутить к нему. Как это сделать эффективно - пока не знаю. Есть метод `webView.Surface.Scroll()`, но я еще не разобрался, как он работает. Пока, при необходимости, делаю средствами js, с выходом из метода для отрисовки.
- Также не знаю, как обойтись без сохранения в файл и меня это удручает.

Comment: Для того, чтобы сфотать всю страницу можно после ее загрузки получить ее высоту вот так `var y = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight)").ToString();`. ну и после этого подписаться на `surface.Resized` и выполнить `webView.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));`